# Does socket IO need to serve HTML to work?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

So, I am quite puzzled. I have a socket IO server that runs OK, and the HTML web client does connect to it. But, I can't emit anything. I'm using xampp to serve webpages, but does socket IO need to serve content for it to receive and send data? It's weird that I connect OK,but that's it, no emit function works.
Here's my code..

```js
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(client){ console.log("Connected OK."); io.emit('message',"data"); });
io.on('message', function(client){ console.log(client); });
io.listen(8080);
```

***HTML***

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    // Create SocketIO instance, connect

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        alert('Client has connected to the server!');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(event) {
        console.log('Received message from client!', event);
    });
</script>
```

The code above prints "Connected OK" to the NPM console, and it alerts "Client has connected to the server!", but that's it. So my question is, does the NPM server need to serve the HTML to work, or am I doing things wrong?. I use xampp because of PHP and MySQL.

### UPDATE:## The server sends to client just fine, and the client *tries* to send data back, and the server receives the packet. But then it reports: "  engine:polling transport discarded - closing right away +0ms". Is this normal?

Comment: well ask your self this. 
if your client is a browser then you need something it knows how to load. (HTML)
if you client is another process, let's say a node process, you would simply write a these lines in some purely javascript client

Comment: The client is a browser, it should alert the result, as it's just a string.

Comment: in socket.io chat tutorial, they write `require('socket.io')(http);`, not sure if that's the issue but ...

Comment: I'll try that. One second!

Comment: If the client can connect to the server, it's not related to how the `socket.io` server is set up to listen. Try running the server in debug mode: `env DEBUG=* node server.js`

Comment: Saying client didn't complete upgrade. I'll change transport methods.

Comment: The 'Received message from client!' message is logged on the console, did you mistype that as you may be looking to receive the message as an alert and not on the console?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked, as Raj said you probably assumed to see an alert when you're actually logging to console

Comment: I didn't even get the "Received message from client". Hmm. odd.

Comment: Ok, I resolved the issue from server--->client. Was antivirus. However, I tried sending to server, and no avail. What is the proper method  for the client to send to all connected sockets, except itslef?

Comment: I suggest you look at the chat tutorial at socket.io website as they mentioned exactly what you said

Comment: I did, I'm doing the exact same thing as them, except i'm specifying the connect URL.  My emit() just doesn't want to work at all. Frustrating!

Comment: @MythDaWolf clients can't send to all connected sockets directly, that's something only the server can do.

Comment: @robertklep So, what if I send data just to the server,and have the server relay it?

Comment: @MythDaWolf yeah that's how it's generally implemented :D

Comment: @robertklep Yeah, just make clients send a JSON packet and parse server side. I'm so dumb. Thanks so much!